# How to remove old Service Bus Messages from the queue

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

I'm using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` to `PeekMessageAsync()` messages on the queue so I can find previously un-completed messages that need deleting, but calling `CompleteMessageAsync()` is having no effect. ('Completing' a message on the queue is how I presume I remove items? )

As part of my debugging I decided to upgrade to the latest service bus libraries, but the previous library needed a 'LockToken' to call Complete on the message, but that LockToken was consistently empty unless I used 'Receive' instead of 'Peek', but the new library accepts the entire `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` object, but LockToken is also empty on that object anyway.

How can I programatically remove old messages that haven't been properly dealt with previously for whatever reason?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the received/peeked `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` to the `CompleteMessageAsync` method as the API requires the whole message and not just the lock token.

Comment: yeah in the newest library you pass the whole Message, but i started on the older library where i could see the code specifically passing an empty GUID from the LockToken, but the newer library takes the whole Message, and i can inspect it at runtime and notice the LockToken is still empty, obviously each Message in that instance was generated using the appropriate version of library, and I thought it significant that both times the LockToken GUID is empty.